# Delete substring in string of PostgreSQL table

Tags: string, attributes, substring, postgresql-9.2

I have table 'A' in PostgreSQL database:

```
name     fullname
A         A,I,A
B         B,B,S,B
D         D,D,S,E,D
E         E,E,D,G,E
F         F,F,G,F
G         G,E,G,F,G,H,N,G
```

How receive table 'B' with column 'correctname' (fullname) where in each row no matching substrings from 'name' field:

```
name  correctname
A      I
B      S
D      S,E
E      D,G
F      G
G      E,F,H,N
```

Sample of data:

```
CREATE TABLE test(name TEXT, fullname TEXT);

INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('A','A,I,A');
INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('B','B,B,S,B');
INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('D','D,D,S,E,D');
INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('E','E,E,D,G,E');
INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('F','F,F,G,F');
INSERT INTO test(name, fullname) VALUES('G','G,E,G,F,G,H,N,G');
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is more a job for the application itself than the sql server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solution](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1042871/udalit-podstroku-v-stroke-tablicy):

```
SELECT 
name
,trim(
REGEXP_REPLACE(fullname,'(,|^)('||name||'(,|$))+',',','cg')
,',')
FROM data;
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(fullname, name||',', ''), ','||name, '') FROM test;
```